# JLabel not showing on frame or on a panel

Tags: java, jlabel

I'm making a calculator as a final for a Java class and I've run into an issue that has halted all progress on the project.  I've got all the buttons on a panel and put onto a frame, but for some reason I can't seem to get a JLabel with the entered numbers to appear on the frame.  I know I'm probably missing something dumb, but help would be appreciated.

packing class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CalculatorFrame
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Calculator");
    JPanel primary = new JPanel();
    JPanel numPad = new JPanel();
    JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    textPanel.add(new NumberText());

    //Grid layout for buttons
    numPad.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));

    //Number Buttons
    numPad.add(new Button1());
    numPad.add(new Button2());
    numPad.add(new Button3());
    numPad.add(new Button4());
    numPad.add(new Button5());
    numPad.add(new Button6());
    numPad.add(new Button7());
    numPad.add(new Button8());
    numPad.add(new Button9());
    numPad.add(new ButtonNeg());
    numPad.add(new Button0());
    numPad.add(new ButtonDec());

    primary.add(textPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    primary.add(numPad, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.getContentPane().add(primary);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

JLabel Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class NumberText extends JLabel
{
private JLabel opNumLabel;
private String opNum;
private double storeNum = 0;
private boolean firstOp = true;

public void NumberText()
{
    opNum = "ur mom lol";
    opNumLabel = new JLabel (" " + opNum);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've actually got **two** JLablels in your code, one that the NumberText class extends, that you add no text to, and that you're adding to the GUI, and one held **within** the same class that you add text to, but that you're not adding to the GUI.

Solution: Don't create a class to override JLabel -- there's no need to do this if you're not extending its behavior. Instead simply use a single JLabel.

Other issues:

- You will want to get most of that code out of the main method and into a class proper where it belongs.
- Use arrays or ArrayLists to simplify your coding and thus your debugging.
- Do you really have a new class for each button? That's a debugging and maintenance nightmare that your really don't want.  Instead will want to use JButtons and change their text and listeners.
- This all suggests that you're over-using inheritance where you instead will want to favor composition in most cases.

Comment: Unfortunately using the main method as I have and having a new class for each button is how my professor wants us to format it.  Thank you so much, I've been able to solve my problem!

Comment: He is very old, hard of hearing, and has been coding since punch card machine code.  Yet these poor practices don't surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

You extended a JLabel but instead of using the instance itself, you created another `JLabel opNumLabel` and used it. Try this way:

```
public class NumberText extends JLabel
{
    private String opNum;
    private double storeNum = 0;
    private boolean firstOp = true;

    public void NumberText()
    {
        super();
        opNum = "ur mom lol";
        this.setText(opNum);
    }
}
```

Also, you may want to think if you really need this `NumberText` instead of using a normal `JLabel`.